# how to disable the field and post it to php simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to disable the amount field if there is an input from the user..
but when I am doing so, it is not getting posted to the PHP page  ...
the value is not getting posted
can you please help so that I can disable it as well as post the data to the next php page.

The JavaScript code used in the html page is given :

```
var x=document.getElementsByName('amount');
       for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        x[i].value = amount; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a field  `disabled` and have it submitted as part of the form data. Being excluded from the form data is what `disabled` means.

Perhaps you want `readonly` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the field to `disabled` when the user writes to it and have a hidden field which gets updated. Hidden fields get submitted and disabled don't.

```
document.getElementById('amount').disabled=true;
document.getElementById('amountHidden').value=document.getElementById('amount').value;
```

Comment: @Deepu Is it compatible with common browsers nowadays? I think I remember this having problems with IE7 and below.. Thanks for the info.